# Modal reopens automatically after clicking the closing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to dynamically create a modal view in a table.

The data used to create the table is comming from a sql database.

Now my problem:

Whenever I click on a button called "Details" the modal view is opening and contains the data it should.
However, when I try to close the view with the "Close"- Button or the X in the top right corner the modal view will close for a second and reopen on its own.
The background will get darker after I do one of the above mentioned operations.

Here comes the tricky part. Whenever I close the view with the escape button on my keyboard, it'll close as it should and I'll get back to my previous view.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "****" , "****");
mysql_select_db("hallo");

$sql= "SELECT * FROM erfassung WHERE Status='Abgeschlossen'";
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $thisId = $row['id'];
    $thisModalId = 'modal'.$thisId;
    $thisModalIdHref = '#'.$thisModalId;
    $thisFormDoneId = $row['id'].'FormDoneId';
  // Create table row
  echo "<tr onclick=\"input\" data-toggle=\"modal\" href='$thisModalIdHref'>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Name'];
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['Betreff'];
   echo "<td>";
   echo "<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-lg\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target='$thisModalIdHref'>";
   echo   "Details";
   echo "</button>";


echo"<div class=\"modal fade\" id='$thisModalId' tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"myModalLabel\" aria-hidden=\"true\">";
 echo "<div class=\"modal-dialog\">";
   echo "<div class=\"modal-content\">";
    echo  "<div class=\"modal-header\">";
     echo  "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>";
      echo  "<h4 class=\"modal-title\" id=\"myModalLabel\">Weitere Information </h4>";
       echo "</div>";
        echo"<div class=\"modal-body\">";
        echo "<dl class=\"dl-horizontal\">";
        echo "<dt>Bereich</dt>";
        echo "<dd>" .$row['Bereich']. "</dd>";
        echo "</dl>";
        echo"</div>";
       echo"<div class=\"modal-footer\">";
       echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>";
       echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Save changes</button>";
      echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>"; //<!-- /.modal-content -->
   echo"</div>";//<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 echo"</div>";//<!-- /.modal -->
    echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

For clarification:

If the $thisModalId is changed to the previous "MyModal" it works, but the button will, as it's supposed to, open the same text.

If you need any more source code or something else, I'd be more than happy to post it.

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Best regards.

Comment: Indented echos are a thing now?

Comment: In order to better answer you, you should provide a clear code, as Damon Gant says, we don't need your php code, 'cause it's HTML and JS problem... Think to helpers please...

Comment: Hey guys, first of all thanks for giving me some tips. I am really new to HTML/JS etc. Do you want me to delete all the echos and format it better or do you want a different kind of source code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ron Hello Ron, Yes I think the helpers like when the problem is ready to solve, with some fiddle. Jsfiddle for javascript, or in your case, with bootstrap : http://bootply.com/new  . You can write your code, and share the link. It will more easy to answer you, mainly when helpers are at work ^^

Comment: Hey Jahnux. Okay, since I am out of work right now I don't have the code at the time. I'll make sure to get my code into bootply and post again on here. Thanks for the reply =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by the fact that your modal `div` is defined inside the element (`tr`) that the onclick handler is defined on. If the close button handler does not consume the click event, it will bubble to the containing elements all the way up (`div, div, div, div, td, tr`). When it gets to the `tr`, the onclick handler will execute and the modal will open again.

Obviously, you can solve this by not having your modal `div` inside your table structure, which doesn't really have a function anyway. This means that you will have to perform more than one separate loop, because the divs have to be all the way outside the table. This does not have to mean that your code will get messy if you take the advice of some of the commenters above and separate your PHP from your HTML a little bit.

Try something like this:

```
<?php
  // Collect data
  mysql_connect("localhost", "****" , "****");
  mysql_select_db("hallo");

  $sql= "SELECT * FROM erfassung WHERE Status='Abgeschlossen'";
  $query=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

  $modals = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $modals[] = array(
      'id' => 'modal' . $row['id'],
      'href' => '#modal' . $row['id'],
      'FormDoneId' => $row['id'] . 'FormDoneId',
      'Name' => $row['Name'],
      'Betreff' => $row['Betreff'],
      'Bereich' => $row['Bereich'],
    );
  }
?>

<table> <!-- Or something -->

<?php
  foreach ($modals as $modal) {
    // Create table rows
?>
  <tr onclick="input" data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo $modal['href'] ?>">
    <td>
    <?php echo $modal['Name'] ?>
    <td>
    <?php echo $modal['Betreff'] ?>
   <td>
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="<?php echo $modal['href'] ?>">
       Details
   </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
  }
?>

</table>

<?php
  foreach ($modals as $modal) {
    // Create modal divs
?>
<div class="modal fade" id='<?php echo $modal['id'] ?>' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Weitere Information </h4>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Bereich</dt>
        <dd><?php echo $modal['Bereich'] ?></dd>
        </dl>
        </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div> //<!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>//<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div>//<!-- /.modal -->
<?php
  }
```

Comment: Hey Spiny Norman. Thank you so much for your suggestion and I do understand that I need to separate between php and HTML. That's why I even appreciate your effort more. I will report back on monday. Have a great weekend!